# Почему не работают методы?

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Делаю CRUD в админке для добавления, редактирования, удаление записей... Первые три метода, это index, create, store работают а остальные 4 нет.
Метод show:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $data = ['team' => Team::find($id)];
        return view('admin.crudTeam.show', $data);
    }
```

Вот страничка под него:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее идет метод edit:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $data = ['team' => Team::find($id)];
        return view('admin.crudTeam.edit', $data);
    }
```

Страничка под него: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следующий метод update:
public function update(Request $request, $id)

```
 {
        $team = Team::find($id);

        $team->name = $request->name;

        if($team->save()){
            Session::flash('update', 'Запись успешна отредактирована');
            return redirect()->route('team.index', $team->id);
        }

    }
```

И последний метод destroy():

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $team = Team::find($id);

        if($team->delete()){
            Session::flash('destroy', 'Запись успешно удалена');
            return redirect()->route('team.index');
        }
    }
```

На страничке show, жму на кнопку "Редактировать" и соответственно перебрасывает на стр edit, изменяю данные(указал только поле name, ибо не работает) жму "Изменить" должен происходить aciton team.update и должно средиректить на главную страницу, но ничего из этого не работает, а редиректит на страницу show. И также с методом destory() жму на кнопку "Удалить" и должен быть редирект на гланвую страницу с уведомлением, но ничего не происходит, а редиректит на главную страницу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML-формы не поддерживают действия PUT, PATCH и DELETE. Поэтому при определении маршрутов PUT, PATCH и DELETE, вызываемых из HTML-формы, вам надо добавить в неё скрытое поле _method. Подробности [тут](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/routing#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0) или [тут](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing).

То есть, в форме надо поставить метод `post` и добавить скрытое поле с помощью хелпера `{{ method_field('PUT') }}`. Для удаления аналогично: в форме метод `post` и скрытое поле с помощью хелпера `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}`.